# How can I create an expandable blog post in html/css/js with a text preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="blog-post">

     <h2>My second blog post</h2>
     <p><em>November 21, 2018</em></p><br>

     <p>Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam. Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam.</p>

</div>

<div class="blog-post">

     <h2>My first blog post</h2>
     <p><em>November 14, 2018</em></p><br>

     <p>Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam. Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam.</p>

</div>
```

I want to have the text of the blog post fade out at the bottom, and onclick expand to get the whole height of the blog post.

Comment: once you click on the blog post you need to show the entire blog content is that what you meant?

Comment: yes                      (chracter limit)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.blog-post__read-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $moreText = $(this).siblings('.blog-post__text').find('.blog-post__expandable-text--visually-hidden');
    if ($moreText.length) {
        $moreText.removeClass('blog-post__expandable-text--visually-hidden').addClass('blog-post__expandable-text');
    }
});
```

```css
.blog-post__expandable-text--visually-hidden {
    /* https://gist.github.com/marcol/3979586 */
 position: absolute !important;
 clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
 clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
 padding:0 !important;
 border:0 !important;
 height: 1px !important; 
 width: 1px !important; 
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-post">

     <h2>My second blog post</h2>
     <p><em>November 21, 2018</em></p><br>

     <p class="blog-post__text">
         Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos.
         <span class="blog-post__expandable-text--visually-hidden">Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam. Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam.</span>
     </p>
     <a href="#" class="blog-post__read-more">Read more</a>

</div>

<div class="blog-post">

     <h2>My first blog post</h2>
     <p><em>November 14, 2018</em></p><br>

     <p class="blog-post__text">
         Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. 
         <span class="blog-post__expandable-text--visually-hidden">Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam. Reque augue meliore ei pro, lorem volumus ocurreret eu per. No solum errem laoreet vel, his vero dicam et, ius volutpat assueverit ad. Ei partem eirmod propriae eos. Nulla debet fastidii vim ei, at verterem accommodare eam.</span>
     </p>
     <a href="#" class="blog-post__read-more">Read more</a>

</div>
```

An easy solution with the help of jQuery. The expandable part has a class to make it visually hidden. The on-click function removes it then.